# Fixed Navigation Bars

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in the middle of experimenting with creating web pages and have come across a problem when trying to make a fixed navigation bar to the top of a web page while scrolling.

I'm able to get the navigation bar fixed to the page using

```
position:fixed;
```

but, the problem i'm having is the content below the nav bar (Main content) is pushing to the top of the page instead of staying directly underneath my fixed nav.

I've tried using margins to correct this problem, but doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the code???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmarine/Lf20gau5/

Comment: It's a tad messed, as the images arn't displaying but you'll get the general idea.

Comment: add some z-index to header and margin-top(equal to header height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `position:fixed` you removed the affected element from the actual flow of the document.

The quickest and most effective work around is to wrap your content in a div and displace it from the top of the page by the same amount as your nav...

```
<div class="fixed">my nav stuff</div>
<div class="my-pushed-content">my content is here</div>
```

css:

```
.fixed { 
    position:fixed; height: 50px; 
 }
.my-pushed-content {
    position: relative //or absolute depending on your needs
    top: 50px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No probs... only other problem im getting now, (scroll works fine now) but as im scrolling down, the nav bar seems to be positioned behind the main content div positioned relative? not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: It's ok! used z-index. Thanks